# How to convert CMYK/RGB TIFF to RGB JPEG using PHP IMagick

Tags: php, tiff, imagick, cmyk, image-conversion

I have a PHP application which needs to deal with incoming TIFF files. I have *neither* control nor knowledge over the colorspaces of this TIFFs and the application should store all incoming images as RGB JPEGs.

Problem is, incoming TIFF files are anything: CMYK, RGB, [some sort of YCbCr wrapped in sRGB](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=21361&p=87203&hilit=tiff#p87203), and so on, and I need to convert them somehow to RGB JPEGs before saving.

**I need some sort of a conversion function in PHP which uses IMagick extension which can get any binary TIFF data and convert it to proper RGB JPEG binary data.** It needs to handle different colorspaces inside TIFF images correctly. Output format (RGB JPEG) stays the same for any input file.

The following obvious solution converts some CMYK TIFFs correctly, some CMYK TIFFs get inverted colors and YCbCr RGB TIFFs get totally corrupted by red overlay:

```
$converter = new IMagick();
$converter->setResourceLimit(6, 1);
$converter->readImageBlob($data);

if ($converter->getImageColorspace() != IMagick::COLORSPACE_RGB
    && $converter->getImageColorspace() != IMagick::COLORSPACE_GRAY
) {
    $icc_rgb = file_get_contents('sRGB_v4_ICC_preference.icc');
    $converter->profileImage('icc', $icc_rgb);
    $converter->setImageColorspace(IMagick::COLORSPACE_RGB);
}

$converter->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$converter->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$converter->setImageCompressionQuality(60);

$converter->resizeImage(1000, 1000, IMagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1, true);
$converter->stripImage();

$result = $converter->getImagesBlob();
```

This solution is taken from there: http://blog.rodneyrehm.de/archives/4-CMYK-Images-And-Browsers-And-ImageMagick.html Obviously, it doesn't work for all colorspaces, because it doesn't detect them reliably. As you can see, it even uses the sRGB_v4 ICC color profile downloaded from [it's homepage](http://www.color.org/srgbprofiles.xalter#v4pref).

Google finds me one particular solution to the red overlay problem (just one of the conversion screw-ups), but it's only for console and when you know *beforehand* that you deal with YCbCr images:

```
convert some.tif -set colorspace YCbCr -colorspace RGB some.jpg
```

I can live with `passthru`-ing `convert` and pass to convert all the magical switches needed, but I suppose I need to detect the source image's colorspace beforehand and call a `identify | grep` before every `convert` in an otherwise PHP application is an overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced this same issue.
It also came up in the [imagick forums](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=22148) and the correction was pushed into ImageMagick 6.8.0-4 .

So upgrading should solve this issue. I've upgraded to ImageMagick 6.8.1-9 and haven't encountered this since.

Comment: Im using 6.7.7.7 and it works also - i just grabbed some profile files and im adding not only cmyk profile but also srgb one - then its working without upgrading what is quite forbidden on server the page is:(